Examine procfs for scratch-based container
I'm developing an application that I'm shipping as a Docker image.  My application consists of a single executable file that links just against libc and libcrypto.  I'm thinking about making my image smaller by statically linking the executable and putting it inside of a scratch image.
My problem comes from my testing.  During testing, I want to confirm that my application, which listens on several ports (TCP and UDP), stood up properly.   I have been doing this by running cat /proc/net/<file> via docker exec.  However, with a scratch image, I won't have access to cat or even sh.
I know that I could, during testing, throw BusyBox inside the container.  However, is there a way to examine the proc file system using only docker?
I tried
docker cp the_container:/proc/net/tcp .

but got the error

Error response from daemon: Could not find the file /proc/net/tcp in container the_container


You can't do it with just docker, but you can do it without injecting anything into the container. Use nsenter to enter the container network namespace while still using the host mount namespace:
container_pid=$(docker container inspect the_container --format '{{ .State.Pid }}')
nsenter -t "$container_pid" -n

This will get you a shell in which you can inspect the container network configuration, including the contents of things in /proc/net (and /proc/<pid>/net).

Is nsenter available on Mac?

You didn't mention in your question that you're using MacOS. nsenter, like docker itself, only runs on Linux. On a Mac, Docker is running in a Linux virtual machine, and the nsenter command is probably available in that virtual environment.
